# exporting multiple csv files as a single csv using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am using Angular's `ngCSV` directive to export my json array into a CSV file. I have to export multiple csv sheets as a single CSV file. Please let me know how to get this using Angularjs or pure javascript?

Comment: Can you add some example code?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your data. Find a way to join (`Array.concat`) your data before passing it on to `ngcsv`.

Without any example, I can only give you a generic answer.

Comment: Thanks orange for your answer. I found that we cannot use `csv` for getting this feature. If we concat, we will get a single csv file which can be opened using excel.